# Python KeyError: '' for automatic language detection

Tags: python

i'm doing an automatic language detection in python using stopwords

but i'm getting KeyError when trying to test the code.
this is the code

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

def scoreFunction(wholetext):
    dictiolist={}
    scorelist={}
    NLTKlanguage = ["dutch","finnish","german","italian","portuguese","spanish","turkish","danish","english"," french","hungarian","norwegian","russian","swedish"]
    FREElanguages = [""]
    languages= NLTKlanguages + FREElanguages
    for lang in NLTKlanguages:
        dictiolist[lang]=stopwords.words(lang)
        tokens=nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(wholetext)
        tokens=[t.lower() for t in tokens]
        freq_dist=nltk.FreqDist(tokens)
    for lang in languages:
        scorelist[lang]=0
    for word in freq_dist.keys()[0:20]:
        if word in dictiolist[lang]:
            scorelist[lang]+=1
    return scorelist

def whichLanguage(scorelist):
    maximum=0
    for item in scorelist:
        value = scorelist[item]
        if maximum<value:
            maximum = value
            lang = item
    return lang
```

whene i run it scoreFunction("hillo my name is osfar and i'm genius") 
i get the error 
    Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in

```
scoreFunction("hello my name is osfar and i'm very genius") 
File "C:/Users/osama1/Desktop
/fun-test", line 17, in scoreFunction 
if word in dictiolist[lang]:
KeyError: ''
```

Comment: Add all relevant information to your actual post, not in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the following block of code:

```
for word in freq_dist.keys()[0:20]:
    if word in dictiolist[lang]:
    scorelist[lang]+=1
```

You're using the variable `lang` in this for loop, but you aren't defining it anywhere. Which means that its value is undefined; as it happens, its value is "" (the empty string) because that was the last value it had in your previous for loop.

What you apparently meant to do is:

```
for word in freq_dist.keys()[0:20]:
    for lang in languages:
        if word in dictiolist[lang]:
        scorelist[lang]+=1
```

By the way, there's an easier way to do what you're trying to do: use a Counter. See http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#counter-objects for more information.